# PHP code not understand to me. Please explain

Tags: php, arrays, api, associative-array

```
$arr = NSZone::find_all(array('per_page'=>20, 'page'=>1));
```

return result is

```
 [0] => NSZone Object
        (
            [xml_skip_attribs:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => id
                )

            [vals:protected] => Array
                (
                    [total_count] => 3
                )
        )
```

he is accessing

```
arr[0]['vals:protected']['total_count'] in this way arr[0]->total_count()
```

That's mean total_count() is a function whereas according to array structure its look like array index.
**Please Explain me this code, how it work?** What is [vals:protected] and can it be public, private etc as well, Any more explanation you know please?

Comment: Read Up: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not an array but a `print_r($arr)` of the NSZone **Object**, if your not in the class meaning your accessing it in the same scope as your using print_r($arr) and the property's are set to private/protected then you cannot access the values within the object if your outside of it, you would need to add a getter of sort, or change it to public.

If the class using a [__get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) magic method you maybe could access it like:
`$arr->total_count;`

or you could add a method to get it, and access it like:`$arr->getCount();`

```
public function getCount(){
  return $this->vals->total_count;
}
```

But without seeing the class, its hard to tell, so I could be completely out.

Answer (score 2):

According to the output, `arr[0]` is an object (NSZone), which obviously has a `total_count` method returning the value you see in `[total_count]`.

And even though you see the `protected` scope resolution, because `total_count` is an assumed member variable of the `NSZone` class it is available to the `total_count` method.